# What is the pythonic way to have conditional shadowing?

Tags: python, scope

I am attempting to override a function based on a condition, essentially only shadowing a variable conditionally.

```
def a(b): #Line 1
  print "a",b
def c(b):
  if b is None:
    def a2(b):
      print 'local',b
    exec('a=a2')
  a(b) #Line 8
c(5)
c(None)
c(6) #line 11
```

Show print

```
a 5
local None
a 6
```

If I just define a() inside of c(), then it will always shadow locally, and not do what I want. If I add global keyword, it does not do what I want. I eventually got this to work using the exec command, but we all try to avoid this, it just doesn't feel very pythonic.

So my question is this. Without changing lines 1, 2, or 8, what would be a more pythonic way of doing this? (I'm using python2, but if the answer is "Only in python3", I'd be interested)

Before you ask "why can't I change lines 1,2, or 8" I don't want to do something like

```
if b is None:
  def a2(b):
    print 'local',b
else:
  a2 = a
a2(b)
```

Because then I need to change EVERY reference of a to a2, and decrease the readability of the code.

Comment: So having no idea if I'm actually calling `a` or `a2` depending on far removed state changes is any more readable than what you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Pythonic way to do this, because you're directly fighting against the Python LEGB variable model.

Python decides *at compile time* whether there's a local variable in the function body that overshadows the global. So you can't change that up at runtime.

Note that your attempt at defining a new local variable with `exec` may seem to work in one test on one implementation… but it doesn't *always* work in CPython 2.7 or PyPy 2.7-2.5, and it *never* works in CPython 3.4 or Jython 2.5.

---

I don't think you even need this, since you can just *always* create a local named `a`, initialized to the global, and then overwrite it. Or, better, give it a different name so it's less confusing to the reader:

```
def a(b): #Line 1
  print "a",b
def c(b):
  a2 = a
  if b is None:
    def a2(b):
      print 'local',b
  a2(b) #Line 8
```

You can even abbreviate that by using a parameter (in which case you don't have to give it a different name… although personally, I still would):

```
def c(b, a=a):
  if b is None:
    def a(b):
      print 'local',b
  a(b) #Line 8
```

If you're worried about performance, I wouldn't be; the cost of a fast-local store and load is tiny compared to the cost of a global lookup, so it will rarely make an appreciable difference. In fact, from your description of why you don't want to change Line 8, it sounds like you're planning to call the function many times. In that case, a global load, a fast-local store, and a whole bunch of fast-local loads will be a lot faster than a whole bunch of global loads, so you just got an optimization for free. But you can always test and see.

---

If you really want to have something that's like the local namespace but manipulable, the obvious answer is just to use an explicit dict:

```
def a(b): #Line 1
  print "a",b
def c(b):
  n = globals().copy()
  if b is None:
    def a2(b):
      print 'local',b
    n['a'] = a2
  n['a'](b) #Line 8
```

If that's too verbose, you can easily wrap the dict as an object's `__dict__` and use `n.a` instead of `n['a']`, using `SimpleNamespace`, or just:

```
class Namespace(object): pass
n = Namespace()
n.__dict__ = globals().copy()
```

---

Or you can get really tricky and write a decorator that dynamically creates a new function object out of your code object with a custom namespace. But why get tricky when all it does is make your code harder to understand?

Comment: I think these workarounds are trying to make Python behave like PHP and they are not good (pythonic) solutions.

Comment: @BrentWashburne: That's exactly why I start off by saying "There's no Pythonic way to do this", and end with suggesting that if you want something like this, you probably want an explicit namespace, not an implicit one (because all that getting tricky does is make your code harder to understand).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that sometimes `a` is a local, and sometimes it should be global. The fix is to make sure it is *always* local by making it a function parameter, but one that, by default, refers to the function it might shadow.

```
def a(b):
    print "a", b

def c(b, a=a):
    if b is None:
        def a(b):
            print 'local', b
    a(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def c(b):
  if b is None:
    def a(b):
      print 'local',b
  else:
    a = globals()['a']
  a(b) #Line 8
```

Comment: I think this really needs to be explained to be of any use

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be improved by using classes:

```
class Base(object):
    def a(self, b):
        print "a",b

class Shadow(Base):
    def a(self, b):
        if b is None:
            print 'local',b
        else:
            super(Shadow,self).a(b)

c = Shadow()
c.a(5)
c.a(None)
c.a(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you are making this far more difficult than needed. Why not:

```
def c(b):
    if b is None:
        print 'local', b
    else:
        print 'a', b
```

This behaves equivalently to your example code and is even comprehensible. Since you don't explain why you want `a` to be bound to an arbitrary function at arbitrary points in the code, there is no good reason to do it and dozens of reasons why not.

If `len()` would give you the length of an iterable most of the time but somewhere in the code was

```
def len(s):
    return 42
```

then your fellow developers would have every right to burn you in effigy (or reject your code from integration).